# Assigning relative record matching 'numbers' to each record in a mysql group_concat function

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using group_concat and an outer join to get all the records in a one to many relationship and return the results in a single row.

The query looks like this:

```
select 
    t.seq as seq, 
    t.subject as subject, 
    t.location as location, 
    t.created as created, 
    t.completed as completed,
    group_concat(n.message, '<br>') as messages  
from tickets t left join tickets_notes n on n.ticket_seq = t.seq
group by t.seq;
```

I need to get and display a count of each message. In other words I need to tell the group concat function which number each note is: (e.g.   group_concat('Note #', @thisnotesnumber, ' ', n.message, '
').

I can't figure out where to pull the '@thisnotenumber' from. The database knows how many elements exist within the n.message array, but I can't figure out how to access that number and increment it for the output.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

So we are getting really close, but the following:

```
select t.seq, t.subject, t.location, t.created, t.completed,
        group_concat(
                concat(
                'Note ',
                @rn := case
                    when @seq = t.seq then @rn + 1
                    when @seq := t.seq then 1
                    else 1
                end,
                ': ', 
                n.message 
                ) order by @rn separator '<br>'
            ) as messages  
from tickets t left join tickets_notes n
on n.ticket_seq = t.seq
group by t.seq
```

Inverses the first two. The first note is second with a number of 1 and the second note out of the table is displayed first with a number of 2. So the numbers are correct, but the order of the first two is inversed.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: mysql version 5.6.34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()` to assign ranks before aggregating:

```
select 
    seq, 
    subject, 
    location, 
    created, 
    completed,
    group_concat(concat(rn, ': ', message) order by rn separator '<br>' ) messages
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        n.message, 
        row_number() over(partition by t.seq order by n.id) rn
    from tickets t 
    left join tickets_notes n on n.ticket_seq = t.seq
) t
group by
    subject, 
    location, 
    created, 
    completed
;
```

Notes:

- to get a consistent output you need some column that can be used to *order* the records being aggregated by `group_concat()`; I assumed column `id` in table `ticket_notes`
- although `seq` is probably the primary key of `tickets`, you should enumerate all non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause. Starting MySQL 5.7, this is mandatory by default
- by default column names are retained in the resultset; aliases like `t.seq as seq` are superfluous (use an alias when you want to change the column name in the resultset)

---

In ealier versions, we can try using variables:

```
select 
    t.seq, 
    t.subject, 
    t.location, 
    t.created, 
    t.completed,
    group_concat(
        concat(
            @rn := case 
                when @seq = t.seq then @rn + 1
                when @seq := t.seq then 1
                else 1
            end, 
            ': ', 
            n.message
        ) 
        order by n.id separator '<br>' 
    ) as messages
from tickets t 
left join tickets_notes n on n.ticket_seq = t.seq
group by 
    t.seq, 
    t.subject, 
    t.location, 
    t.created, 
    t.completed
;
```

`@seq` keeps track of the value of the current `seq`, and `@rn` represents the row number, which is restarts from 1 everytime `seq` changes.

Comment: Sorry - not an option. The architecture is fixed. I need a solution that will work with what I have. Thanks though!

Comment: We are really close. Thanks! Please see my additional post.

Comment: Removing the 'order by @rn' clause seems to fix it, but I am not sure why. Can you polish off my education by telling me why?

Comment: @MarkC.: my mistake, there should be no `rn` in the second query, that’s a copy/paste error from the first query. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This works perfectly in a direct query to mysql. Weird bug is the number doesn't increment when I put this query into php and fire it through a pdo interface. However, that is a different issue than this ticket.